# How to prove or disprove this function is valid kernel?

Tags: kernel-trick, proof

I have the following function

$$
K(x, y) = \begin {cases}
1, & if  ||x - y||_2 \le 1  \\
0, & otherwise
\end{cases}
$$

I'd like to prove (or disprove) that it's a valid kernel function. 
In order for a function to be a kernel, I understand that I have to prove that the kernel matrix is symmetric and positive definite.

It's obvious that the kernel matrix for the above function is symmetric and positive, but how do I prove (or disprove) its definiteness?

Comment: Do you know what the definition of positive definiteness is? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix

Answer (score 4):

For this kernel to be positive definite, the following inequality must be  verified for every $n \in \mathbb N_+$, $x_1, \dots , x_n \in \mathbb R$ and $a_1, \dots , a_n \in \mathbb R$:
$$  \mathcal S = \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_i a_j K(x_i, x_j) \geq 0  $$

Let's take $n=3$, $a_1 = a_2 = 1$ and $a_3 = -1$. Let's suppose that $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 1$ and $x_1 = 2$, so that 
$$ K(x_1, x_2) = 0,$$
$$ K(x_2, x_3) = 1,$$
$$ K(x_1, x_3) = 1.$$

Thus, $$  \mathcal S = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + 2a_2a_3 + 2a_1a_3$$
$$  \mathcal S = -1$$

$K$ is therefore not positive definite.