# Checking if a kernel is valid

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick

The kernel is $K(x,z) = \sum_{i=1}^D (x_i+z_i)$

My approach was trying to express  $K = \phi(x)^T\phi(z) = (x_1 x_2 ... x_D \quad 1 1 ...1)(1 1 ...1\quad z_1 z_2 ... z_D )^T$ where $\phi$ is 2Dx1

The solution says:

K is not a kernel. Consider $x_1 = [1 \quad 0]^T \quad x_2 = [0 \quad 2]^T$. Their kernel matrix has eigenvalues −1 and 5.

What explains this discrepancy?

[EDIT]: Based on the link below and the given $x_1, x_2$, I arrive at $S = 2a_1^2+6a_1a_2+4a_2^2$ Now, how can I choose $a_1,a_2$ to make this negative?

Comment: You can't show that a kernel is valid by constructing a single example which looks good, but you can show it's invalid by constructing a single example which looks bad (in this case, not positive definite.)  See for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183215/how-to-prove-or-disprove-this-function-is-valid-kernel?rq=1, which may be helpful.

Comment: @jbowman: Please see edit above.

Comment: You might be interested in this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/199620/on-the-properties-of-hyperbolic-tangent-kernel/199765#199765

Comment: Response to edit:  $S$ factors as $2(a_1+a_2)(a_1+2a_2)$, which will be negative if $a_1+a_2 > 0$ and $a_1+2a_2 < 0$, for example, $a_1 = 3$ and $a_2 = -2$.

Comment: @jbowman: Thanks! Btw, how do I arrive at the eigenvalues mentioned in the original solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Based on the link below and the given $x_1, x_2$, I arrive at $S = 2a_1^2+6a_1a_2+4a_2^2$ Now, how can I choose $a_1,a_2$ to make this negative?

We can factorize $S$ to obtain
$$
S = 2(a_1 + a_2) (a_1 + 2 a_2)
$$
so if we want $S < 0$, we need to choose $a_1, a_2$ such that exactly one of $(a_1 + a_2) <0$ or $(a_1 + 2a_2)<0$. This is because the product of two positive numbers is positive and the product of two negative numbers is positive but the product of a positive number and a negative number is negative.

Since this problem is under-determined, a useful way to go about solving it is to fix $a_1$ at some value and then find $a_2$ that satisfies our criteria. Arbitrarily, I chose $a_1 = -1$. This gives

$$
S = 2(-1 + a_2) (-1 + 2 a_2)
$$

Now I decided to make the second factor negative and the third factor positive. This means we need $a_2 - 1 < 0$ but $2a_2 -1 >0$. Together, these inequalities provide $\frac{1}{2} < a_2 < 1$. We can arbitrarily choose any $a_2$ in that interval.

Thus one solution among many is $a_1 = -1, a_2 = \frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: That helps! Btw, how do I arrive at the eigenvalues mentioned in the original solution?

Comment: Compute the kernel matrix using the given inputs. For 2 inputs, the kernel is $2 \times 2$, so you can compute the eigenvalues trivially by hand because the characteristic polynomial is a quadratic, and solving quadratic is easy (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). More information: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the quadratic formula and characteristic equation. Maybe I'm missing something obvious in this "Compute the kernel matrix using the given inputs"

Comment: You wrote the general expression for computing an element of the kernel matrix in your question. A kernel matrix for 2 vectors has 4 elements. How do you use your expression to populate the 4 elements of the matrix using $x_1, x_2$?

Comment: So that gives the Kernel matrix as [2 3;3 4] but this gives the eigenvalues as -0.16 and 6.16

Comment: That agrees with my computations. I'm not sure why the solution is different.